# SyncAdapter for Android consuming WCF-service with NTLM credentials

Tags: android, authentication, rest, ntlm, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to develop a rest-client-application following the patterns of [Dobjanschi](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html).

Therefore I'm using the sample from google "[samplesync](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)", but I have the problem that I need to consume a WCF-service which requires a NTLM-authentication.

I have already sucessfully established the connection to the webservice, by following the schema from [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html).

But as I said I want to follow the patterns for developing webservices, so my question is how can i integrate the ntlm-authentication in the sync model from google?

I think it must be set somewhere in the AuthenticatorActivity or in the Authenticator class but I don't know precisely where and how to do it, in order to establish a correctly working SyncAdapter.

If someone can help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

Already thanks for your time and your support.